# Store variable anonymous type within linq query with oData webapi

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first, odata

I'm trying to return a foo id where bar is active and one of the inherited tables on baz (foobar) has the correct Ids associated to it: see code snipped below.

```
var v = Utilities.newContainer()
           .foo
           .Select(f => new { f, fb = (f.baz as foobar) })
           .Where(res => res.fb.Id1 == iId1
               && res.fb.Id2 == iId2
               && res.fb.Id3 == iId3
               && res.f.bar.IsActive)
        .Select(res => new { res.f.Id })
        .Single();
```

I am doing this to avoid having to cast baz as foobar for each id comparison.

The following error message appears when running this query:

> Constructing or initializing instances of the type <>f__AnonymousType0`2[foo,foobar] with the expression (f.baz As foobar) is not supported.

I can get this query to work if I remove the top anonymous type and cast 3 times see below.

```
var v = Utilities.newContainer()
           .foo
           .Where(f => (f.baz as foobar).Id1 == iId1
               && (f.baz as foobar).Id2 == iId2
               && (f.baz as foobar).Id3 == iId3
               && f.bar.IsActive)
        .Select(f => new { f.Id })
        .Single();
```

How can I get the top query to work?

Edit:
The question linked to this one as duplicate does not solve this issue. I have no issue projecting into an anonymous type as the working query already does that. Adding .AsEnumerable() to a query would force the whole f object to be returned before narrowing down to an Id, which I do not want to do.

Comment: I don't have an issue projecting into a custom type, my working query already does that. The issue is trying to store a foobar variable so I don't have to cast baz on every where clause.

Comment: I think it's because Linq to Entities only support casting primitive or enumeration types (I'm assuming its LINQ to entities from your edit), i believe if you as AsEnumerable() before the Select statement it will work

Comment: It's sort of linq to entities, however the communication between the client and the models on the service is using oData REST, which limits the useable features of linq.

Comment: so - there's your answer...

Comment: My understanding is if you call AsEnumerable() the entire foo object will be loaded into memory before retrieving the Id. If this is correct, is there no way to just return foo.Id without loading foo into memory first?